# google analytics counts redirects from chrome extension

Tags: google-analytics

I have a chrome extension that redirects the user back to his dashboard. sometimes they might be on another domain and hit the extension and redirects to the dashboard on my website.

Google analytics show this as part of the traffic, when in fact it should not be! it has polluted a great deal of the traffic and I can't tell which one are actual referrals and which one were just a user hitting the extension and being redirected to my website.

Is there a way to filter these out and prevent this event from being tracked?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Webmaster Tools you can exclude parameters.  I would do this so Google will not index those parameters as separate urls.

You will see parameters like "utm_source" and "utm_medium".

Next add this to your .htaccess:

```
#Removes Campaign Url Parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((.*?)&|)utm_
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

I would test any .htaccess mods on test server first but I can verify that code works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you append something like ?extensiontraffic to the URLs used in your Chrome extension and then apply a profile filter in GA to remove any of these visits from your reports?